# Complex continuity proof

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

Show that continuity of complex functions holds under addition.

---

We want to show given two functions $f,g\colon A\to\mathbb{C}$, where $A\subset\mathbb{C}$ is a domain, and some sequence $(a_n)$ such that $a_n\to a$ for some $a\in A$ we have that $(f+g)(a_n)\to (f+g)(a)$.

Define the functions $u,v,w,t\colon A\to\mathbb{R}$. We write $f(z) = u(z)+iv(z)$ and $g(z)=w(z)+it(z)$. Note that

$$f(a_n)\to f(a)\implies
 \begin{cases}
  \Re{(f(a_n))} = u(a_n) \to \Re{(f(a_n))} = u(a), \\
  \Im{(g(a_n))} = v(a_n) \to \Im{(f(a_n))} = v(a),
\end{cases}$$

$$g(a_n)\to g(a)\implies 
 \begin{cases}
  \Re{(g(a_n))} = w(a_n) \to \Re{(g(a))}=w(a), \\
  \Im{(g(a_n))} = t(a_n) \to \Im{(g(a))}=t(a).
 \end{cases}
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
  (f+g)(a_n) &= f(a_n)+g(a_n) \\
       &= \big(u(a_n)+iv(a_n)\big) + \big(w(a_n)+it(a_n)\big) \\
       &= \big(u(a_n) + w(a_n)\big) + i\big(v(a_n)+t(a_n)\big) \\
       &\to \big(u(a) + w(a)\big) + i\big(v(a)+t(a)\big) \\
       &= \big(u(a) + iv(a)\big) + \big(w(a) + it(a)\big) \\
       &= f(a) + g(a) \\
       &= (f+g)(a)      
\end{align*}

---

Is this correct working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a complete proof.  The "real analogue" is that if $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$ are all real numbers, then $x_n+y_n\to x+y$.  Here you are saying that $\alpha(a_n) + i\beta(a_n) + \gamma(a_n) + i\delta(a_n)\to\alpha(a) + i\beta(a) + \gamma(a) + i\delta(a)$ because $\alpha(a_n)\to \alpha(a)$, $\beta(a_n)\to\beta(a)$, and so on.  But you can't say this, because you aren't just adding together real numbers ($i\beta(a_n)$ is not a real number, for instance).

What you can do is write $$\alpha(a_n) + i\beta(a_n) + \gamma(a_n) + i\delta(a_n)=(\alpha(a_n)+\gamma(a_n)) + i(\beta(a_n) + \delta(a_n))$$ and then use the real analogue to conclude that $\alpha(a_n)+\gamma(a_n)\to \alpha(a)+\gamma(a)$ and $\beta(a_n)+\delta(a_n)\to\beta(a)+\delta(a)$.  To finish the proof, you now need to use the fact that a sequence of complex numbers converges iff the real parts and imaginary parts each converge.

Comment: This makes sense. However while reading this it has brought to my attention that I am confused with another part of this proof. How do we know that $\alpha(a_n)\to \alpha(a), \beta(a_n)\to\beta(a), \gamma(a_n)\to\gamma(a)$ and $\delta(a_n)\to\delta(a)$?

Comment: You know $f(a_n)\to f(a)$ since $f$ is continuous, and so again you use the fact that a sequence of complex numbers converges iff the real parts and imaginary parts each converge to get $\alpha(a_n)\to\alpha(a)$ and $\beta(a_n)\to\beta(a)$, and similarly for $g$.

Comment: But if $f(a_n)\to f(a)$ and $g(a_n)\to g(a)$ then why can't we say $(f+g)(a_n) = f(a_n)+g(a_n) \to f(a) + g(a) = (f+g)(a)$? It seems like what I was doing was extra work?

Comment: How do you know $f(a_n)+g(a_n)\to f(a)+g(a)$?

Comment: Since $f(a_n)\to f(a)$ and $g(a_n)\to g(a)$ adding both these together yields the desired result.

Comment: Do you know that you can add limits when talking about complex numbers rather than real numbers?  I thought that was basically what you were trying to prove.

Comment: Final question, since $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ have a complex domain $A\subset\mathbb{C}$, do we still consider them real functions?

Comment: Well, that depends on context.  If you want to invoke a theorem that says "a sum of continuous real functions is continuous", then you need to see what definition of "real function" that theorem is using.  But the argument given in my answer uses only sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ formed by values of the functions, so it doesn't depend on their domain.

Comment: But you have used $a_n$ in your answer, that is defined as a complex sequence of numbers converging to $a$.

Comment: But when I use the property that the sum of the limits is the limit of the sums, I'm using it with the sequences $\alpha(a_n)$, $\beta(a_n)$, etc, which are sequences of real numbers.